# How to increment number using animate with comma using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, increment, number-formatting

I'm trying to increment a number inside an element on page. But I need the number to include a comma for the thousandth place value. (e.g. 45,000 not 45000)

```
<script>
// Animate the element's value from x to y:
  $({someValue: 40000}).animate({someValue: 45000}, {
      duration: 3000,
      easing:'swing', // can be anything
      step: function() { // called on every step
          // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
          $('#el').text(Math.round(this.someValue));
      }
  });
</script>
<div id="el"></div>
```

How can I increment a number using animate with comma?

Comment: Have a look at this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327046/jquery-number-formatting

Comment: I would store the number in a data attribute, then show the comma formatted version of the number in the element.  When you increment it, just increase the data version and replace the formatted version.

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-using-jquery

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/4v2wK/

Feel free to change it more for your need, you can also look at the currency formatter, Hope this will fit your need `:)`

**Code**

```
// Animate the element's value from x to y:
  var $el = $("#el"); //[make sure this is a unique variable name]
  $({someValue: 40000}).animate({someValue: 45000}, {
      duration: 3000,
      easing:'swing', // can be anything
      step: function() { // called on every step
          // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
          $el.text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
      }
  });

 function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
    return val;
  }
```

**output*
[image]

Comment: any idea why the number is not the same? I am taking about the circle around the output.

Comment: Hiya @AdrianFlorescu umm how do you mean, sorry not sure what are you asking? `:)` you mean why the output is not say for example: 44,444? like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hVpqD/

Comment: @Tats_innit exactly, but looks like this is because of the animate steps. I replaced the value on complete with the original value. complete : function(){
            where.text(endNr);
        }   http://jsfiddle.net/5yBt8/10/

Comment: You should also add a complete function as such:
step:function(){
//..
},
complete:function(){
$el.text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
}

Answer (score 12):

You should also add a complete function as such:

```
step:function(){
    //..
},
complete:function(){
    $el.text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
}
```

Updated Fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4v2wK/375/)

Comment: Why? I'm fairly certain that the `step` function will be called even on the last animation step. The `complete` function is used to attach a callback to run after all steps are completed.

Comment: Sometimes it wasnt showing a good last result, it was random at the end, sometimes 45000, sometimes 4995 and so on, so i've added this function, and now it works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and used `toLocaleString` to put commas
As suggested in the above answer I found the result deviating from the real value and I solved that by adding the `complete` callback function that is called when the animation is finished

```js
value_to_be_shown=100000000
// Animate a value from 0 to `value_to_be_shown`
$({
    someValue: 0 // Starting value
}).animate({
    someValue: value_to_be_shown // Ending value
}, {
    duration: 1000, // Animation duration in milliseconds
    easing: 'swing', // Easing function to control acceleration of the animation
    step: function () { // Function to be called on every step of the animation
        // Update the element's text with the rounded-up value of `someValue`:
        $('#el_id').text(Math.round(this.someValue).toLocaleString('en-US'));
    },
    complete: function () { // Function to be called after the animation completes
        // Update the element's text with the final value
        $('#el_id').text(value_to_be_shown.toLocaleString('en-US'));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:gray;width:300px;text-align:center;height:100px;padding:20px;margin:20vh auto;">
<div style="font-size:2rem;font-weight:bold" id="el_id">0</div>
</div>
```