# Increment number using animate with comma: Part 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

```
// Animate the element's value from x to y:
  function stepNum () {
 $({someValue: 40000}).animate({someValue: 45000}, {
  duration: 3000,
  easing:'swing', // can be anything
  step: function() { // called on every step
      // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
      $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
   }
 });

function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
    val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}
return val;
}
}

$('.scene06').waypoint(function() { 
stepNum(); 
}, { offset: 400 })
```

So, the code has evolved a bit.

Since this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227858/jquery-increment-number-using-animate-with-comma?answertab=active#comment23230442_16227858).

I've wrapped the increment inside a function. And it's triggered by user scrolling down (via [waypoint.js](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)). But how can I get this to animate just once and not repeatedly each time somebody scrolls over it. Ideas?

Comment: I've tried using promise(), done(), end(). But those just kill any other animations going-on on the page. I'm stumped.

Comment: i dont quite understand what you mean. So everything someone scrolls, the stepNum() gets called? And it's code is the animation from the link you posted?

Comment: I've added the rest of the code for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass a triggerOnce parameter

```
$('.scene06').waypoint(function() {  
{
    stepNum();
},  
{ 
    offset: 400,
    triggerOnce: true 
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help :) Google probably deserves some credit on this one too

Comment: Not sure why they impose a timer on the answer button. @Luigi Siri. But I'll make sure to do that. Cheers!