# Format Numbers in multilingual site

Tags: jquery

In my multilingual site I have a li contain the total count of the product

```
<li id="totalCount" style="display:none" data-total="@numberOfItems" data-resultcount="@results.Count()">totalCount</li>
```

and there is a div

```
<div class="resultCount">Results
 <span class=rCount></span></div>
```

and using Jquery to give the total count to the span

```
 $('.rCount').text([$('#totalCount').attr('data-resultcount')]);
```

Here I need to format the total count.If I get total count as 1236 then in English site it will be 1,236 in danish site it will be 1.236 .how can we format the total in jquery.can anyone help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Number Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327046/jquery-number-formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Number.toLocaleString()`.

```
var num = $('#totalCount').attr('data-resultcount');
num = parseInt(num).toLocaleString();
$('.rCount').text(num);
```

Comment: thanks.it is working in English site as 1,236 but not in Danish

Comment: It should work. It's detecting the locale automatically based on the user's browser/system. If it's possible in your scenario, you could force it to use a Danish format. `Number.toLocaleString('de-DE')`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take this code:

```
var total = $('#totalCount').attr('data-resultcount');
```

Apply any update you need to the "total" variable.
Then pass the value to the text function.

```
 $('.rCount').text(total)
```