# Format a bootstrap table with dollar sign and thousand separator

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, currency-formatting

I am trying to format my bootstrap table, so that I can read $12,000,000 instead of 12000000  + its footer (suming up columns)
I understand this can be donne inserting a javascript function +CSS.
Thanks for your help.

Here is the code of my table.

```
<table id="exampleTableFromData" data-sort-order="desc" data-mobile-responsive="true" data-search="true" data-show-footer="true" data-footer-style="footerStyle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="Customers" data-sortable="true" data-align="left">Customer</th>

            <th data-field="RM" data-sortable="true" data-align="right" data-footer-formatter="totalFormatter">Sales</th>

            <th data-field="BO" data-sortable="true" data-align="right" data-footer-formatter="totalFormatter">Discount</th>

            <th data-field="GGR" data-sortable="true" data-align="right" data-footer-formatter="totalFormatter">Net</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: You should have added some more unrelated language tags ...

Comment: Done-is it better now ?

Comment: Assuming this is `PHP`, try [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: which server side language do you  use?

Comment: The server side returns a json

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327046/jquery-number-formatting there's your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok found the way to have the right format for the footer with this script

```
function totalFormatter(data) {

  var total = 0;

  if (data.length > 0) {

    var field = this.field;

    total = data.reduce(function(sum, row) {
      return sum + (+row[field]);
    }, 0);
    var num = '$' + total.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    return num;
  }

  return '';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in `PHP` try the following:

```
$num = 12000000;
echo '$' . number_format($num);    // $12,000,000
echo '$' . number_format($num, 2); // $12,000,000.00
```

Comment: not in a table powered by jquery