# Number formatting jquery

Tags: jquery

We have a numeric text field in an html form.
For example sales 1500000
We wish to add number formatting(add ',' after every 3 digits),right after the user finishing editing that field so it will show as 1,500,000. Is there a simple way to it in jquery without affecting the field data (just change it in the display of this field)?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327046/jquery-number-formatting

Answer (score 0):

[Format numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript) May be it will be helpful Or You may try :

```
function FormatNumber(val){
    if(val == "" || val == null){
        return "0.00";
    }
    var result = RemoveComma(val).toFixed(2); 
    return result.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function RemoveComma(val){
    var result = Number(String(val).replace(/,/g, ""));
    return result;
}
```