# jQuery number formatting not working correctly

Tags: jquery, number-formatting

i have user input containing a number with decimals. i have to modify that input to a format which i can use to do calculations on.

So, consider the following:

```
input         -->    should become
10,123.15     -->    10.123,15
10.123,15     -->    10.123,15
10,123.1      -->    10.123,10
10.123,1      -->    10.123,10
10,123        -->    10,123,00
10.123        -->    10.123,00
10.123,13562  -->    10.123,14
10,123.13562  -->    10.123,14
```

In other words: use dots for thousand separators, comma for decimal separator en always return a rounded up, two decimal number.

I tried using regex'es, substr, round, but i'm kinda stuck. I have it working now for the first two examples mentioned above but now it doesn't work for the rest.

Been looking it at this for a few hours now but maybe you can help me with it?
[JQuery Number Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327046/jquery-number-formatting) did help me a bit but still it's not working for all of the examples above.

I would be so happy if someone could help me with this!

Comment: If comma before dot, 1. remove commas, 2. use toFixed(2), 3. reformat using one of many european number formatters - If dot before comma replace dots with nothing, replace commas with dots. rinse and repeat

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toLocaleString()` to achieve this if you provide a locale which formats number in the manner you require; `de-DE` for example. Try this:

```js
var foo = '10,123.15'; // number as string
var num = parseFloat(foo.replace(',', '')); // remove the , and convert to float
console.log(num.toLocaleString('de-DE')); // format to locale
```

Answer (score 0):

thx for answering!

I tried them and i had some more ideas because of it. I've solved it by iterating the input val from right to left while testing if the char is a comma or dot. Then act accordingly. Works ok now!

Thanks again,

Regards