# Format number in entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting

I have a web page generated by an Angular web app. I do not have access to the code that generates the page. In this page numbers with many digits (up to 7-8 digits each) are shown. Is there the possibility (via javascript, jquery or something else) to format all the numbers that are shown?
I cannot use angular code, because I can only "inject" code via editors made available by the app.

Example

```
1005498900.05 -> 1,005,498,900.05
```

Comment: https://devdocs.io/angularjs~1.5/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: You may take a further look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327046/jquery-number-formatting . using that function, you can get (apparently) the equivalent of the angularjs filter function (see it live here: https://jsfiddle.net/sq432af9/). However, you need to fecth the data from the DOM after it has been rendered, hence we need further informations about whether the number fields have a specific class or are just placed randomly in the DOM.