# Jquery to add dots after 3 numbers/digits

Tags: javascript

I want to add a dot after 3 numbers like
I have a input where the outcome comes  with the id `price`

```
100 = 100
1000 = 1.000
10000 = 10.000
1000000 = 100.000
1000000 = 1.000.000
```

I need to do it without plugins

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this.  It is low level logic.  Just like you don't need jQuery to add two number together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Number Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327046/jquery-number-formatting)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString using e.g. `'de-DE'`

Comment: The problem is the links you have shared i already tried and i need dot after every 3 numbers without the decimals

Comment: May include your try?

Answer (score 8):

You could try this:

```
function getNumberWithCommas(number) {
    return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this alternative using the function `reduceRight`

```js
function format(str) {
  var length = 3,
    separator = ".",
    count = 0,
    result = str.split('').reduceRight((a, c) => {
      if (count === length) {
        a.push(separator);
        count = 1;
      } else count++;
      a.push(c);
      return a;
    }, []).reverse().join('');
    
    return result;
}


console.log(format('100'))
console.log(format('1000'))
console.log(format('10000'))
console.log(format('1000000'))
console.log(format('100000000'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending the prototype of number version of the @Alen Nikolov's answer.

```
  if (!Number.prototype.dotFormat){
     Number.prototype.dotFormat = function(){
        return this.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
     };
  }

  console.log( 1234567.dotFormat() );
```

Answer (score 0):

just another way... But it's just for fun. The right answer that I upvote and you should accept is @Alen Nikolov's one. Simply replace with regular expression

```js
  const formatNum = n => Array.from(String(n)).reverse().map((a,i) => 
  {if((i%3==0)&&(i>0))return a+"."; return a;
 }).reverse().join("");
 
  console.log(formatNum(10000000000));
  console.log(formatNum(1000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test this code.

```
var price = parseInt(priceStr);
 $(element).val(price.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
```