# How to modify this script to allow another character to be typed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that adding comma to a number in a string format. This script is preventing `.` to be typed. My purpose is to allow one dot (only one).

This is my script

```
$('.number_format').on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
});
```

Comment: Check the answers on this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327046/jquery-number-formatting

Answer (score 0):

You should provide examples, but `\D` is equal to `[^0-9]`, so we can just add `.` to that to get `[^0-9.]` --- and `\d` is equal to `[0-9]` so we can also just add `.` to that to get `[0-9.]` so you're left with the following:

```
$('.number_format').on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        return value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "").replace(/\B(?=([0-9.]{3})+(?![0-9.]))/g, ",");
    });
});
```

Use a site like https://regex101.com/ to help you understand what the Regular Expression is doing.